# semaphore on boost

Tags: c++, boost, semaphore

I'm using `named_semaphore` and I would like to declare a semaphore and then ask it the number of processes, but at the moment I get this for example:

```
const unsigned N_CORES = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
named_semaphore SEMAPHORE(open_or_create, PROCESS_NAME, N_CORES);
```

I would first to to declare the SEMAPHORE and at another point get the number of cores.

According to api:

```
  //!Creates a global semaphore with a name, and an initial count. 
  //!If the semaphore can't be created throws interprocess_exception
  named_semaphore(create_only_t, const char *name, unsigned int initialCount);

  //!Opens or creates a global semaphore with a name, and an initial count. 
  //!If the semaphore is created, this call is equivalent to
  //!named_semaphore(create_only_t, ...)
  //!If the semaphore is already created, this call is equivalent to
  //!named_semaphore(open_only_t, ... )
  //!and initialCount is ignored.
  named_semaphore(open_or_create_t, const char *name, unsigned int initialCount);
```

and I have tried:

```
 const unsigned N_CORES = boost::thread::hardware_concurrency();
 named_semaphore SEMAPHORE(create_only, PROCESS_NAME, N_CORES);

 // at other point
 SEMAPHORE(open_or_create, PROCESS_NAME, numberOfCores);
```

but show this error:

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
```

Comment: Do you want to pass to the semaphore later the number of cores? For what I see in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_semaphore.html), this seems not possible.

Comment: because I have situations where I don't use all cores

Comment: I don't think you can change the semaphore counter. As for the `open_or_create`, it won't work either (aside of the error you got) as the count will be ignored. If you find out anything about this please inform back, as I'm interested in this topic too.